# Check If Path Exists Using Fabric

Tags: python, ubuntu, fabric

I am running this code to check whether this directory exists on remote machine or not but this code is checking for the directory on local machine. How can I verify directory on remote machine?

```
rom fabric.api import run, sudo, env
import os

env.hosts = ['remote_server']
env.user = 'ubuntu'
env.key_filename = '/home/ubuntu/ubuntu16-multi.pem'


def Directory_Check():
  DIR_1="/home/ubuntu/test-dir"
  if os.path.exists(DIR_1):
    print "Directory Exist!"
  else:
    print "Directory Does Not Exist!"
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the [`files.exists` function](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.13/api/contrib/files.html#fabric.contrib.files.exists).

```
def check_exists(filename):
    from fabric.contrib import files
    if files.exists(filename):
        print('%s exists!' % filename)
```

And call it with [`execute`](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.13/usage/execution.html#intelligently-executing-tasks-with-execute).

```
def main():
    execute(check_exists, '/path/to/file/on/remote')
```

Comment: This is exact what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

Although the accepted answer is valid for fabric ver 1, for whoever hits this thread while looking for the same thing but for fabric2:

`exists` method from `fabric.contrib.files` was moved to `patchwork.files` with a small signature change, so you can use it like this:

```
from fabric2 import Connection
from patchwork.files import exists

conn = Connection('host')
if exists(conn, SOME_REMOTE_DIR):
   do_something()
```

Answer (score 9):

why not just `keep it simply stupid` as:

```
from fabric.contrib.files import exists

def foo():
    if exists('/path/to/remote/file', use_sudo=True):
      # do something...
```

Comment: is there a way to use it in `local` ?

Comment: @ignivs nope. It is aimed for using on remote hosts https://github.com/fabric/fabric/blob/master/fabric/contrib/files.py#L16

Comment: @andi: you're snippet won't connect to the OP's remote where the env is set at run time in code.  If you set env in code, you have to wrap in an `execute` to pick up the changes to the env.

Answer (score 0):

For newer versions of fabric:

```
def file_exists(connection, full_path):
    try:
        result = connection.run(f'ls -ls {full_path}', hide=True)
        return True
    except:
        return False
```

Example:

```
with connection('1.1.1.1', port=1111) as conn:
    result = file_exists(conn, '/home/user/.bashrc')
```