# How to check If Path Exists Using Fabric2.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, fabric

I am using Fabric2 version and I don't see It has exist method in it to check if folder path has existed in the remote server. Please let me know how can I achieve this in Fabric 2 http://docs.fabfile.org/en/stable/.

I have seen a similar question [Check If Path Exists Using Fabric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44736637/check-if-path-exists-using-fabric), But this is for fabric 1.x version

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can execute the *test* command remotely with the -d option to test if the file exist and is a directory while passing the warn parameter to the run method so the execution doesn't stop in case of a non-zero exit status code. Then the value failed on the result will be True in case that the folder doesn't exist and False otherwise.

```py
folder = '/path/to/folder'
if c.run('test -d {}'.format(folder), warn=True).failed:
    # Folder doesn't exist
    c.run('mkdir {}'.format(folder))
```

Comment: please elaborate your solution at least in a brief way!

Comment: Please add some comments about if part

Answer (score 1):

`exists` method from `fabric.contrib.files` was moved to `patchwork.files` with a small signature change, so you can use it like this:

```
from fabric2 import Connection
from patchwork.files import exists

conn = Connection('host')
if exists(conn, SOME_REMOTE_DIR):
   do_something()
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that currently only works with connections, but not with Serial neither Threading groups:
`File "/Users/alejandro.lorente/.python_venvs/test/lib/python3.10/site-packages/patchwork/util.py", line 114, in inner  return f(*args, **kwargs)`

`File "/Users/alejandro.lorente/.python_venvs/test/lib/python3.10/site-packages/patchwork/files.py", line 31, in exists return runner(cmd, hide=True, warn=True).ok`

`AttributeError: 'GroupResult' object has no attribute 'ok'`

Comment: `patchwork` cannot be used with a modern `fabric2´ 3.x version sadly. https://github.com/fabric/patchwork/pull/46

Answer (score 1):

The below code is to check the existence of the file *(-f)*, just change to *'-d'* to check the existence of a directory.

```py
from fabric import Connection
c = Connection(host="host")
if c.run('test -f /opt/mydata/myfile', warn=True).failed:
   do.thing()
```

You can find it in the Fabric 2 documentation below:
https://docs.fabfile.org/en/2.5/getting-started.html?highlight=failed#bringing-it-all-together

Answer (score -1):

Hi That's not so difficult, you have to use traditional python code to check if a path already exists.

```
from pathlib import Path
from fabric import Connection as connection, task
import os


@task
def deploy(ctx):
    parent_deploy_dir = '/var/www'
    deploy_dir ='/var/www/my_folder'
    host = 'REMOTE_HOST'
    user = 'USER'
    with connection(host=host, user=user) as c:
                with c.cd(parent_deploy_dir):
                if not os.path.isdir(Path(deploy_dir)):
                    c.run('mkdir -p ' + deploy_dir)
```

Comment: No, this checks the path on the host, not on the remote server.